# Section of Etale space over closed subset

Tags: algebraic-geometry, complex-geometry

Let $\mathcal{F} = C^\infty_X$ be a sheaf of smooth function,$X$ be the real line,consider the Etale space $$\text{Et}(\mathcal F) = \bigcup_{x\in X}\mathcal{F}_x$$

We have the canonical projection from $p:\text{Et}(\mathcal{F})\to X$

Define $\mathcal{F}^+$ be the sheaf of the section from $X$ to $\text{Et}(\mathcal{F})$,that is $\mathcal{F}^+(U) =\{s:U\to \text{Et}(\mathcal{F})|p\circ s = \text{id}\}$.Then
We have the natural transformation $\mathcal{F} \to \mathcal{F}^+$.Which is isomorphism.

Which implies that local section of the Etale space $\mathcal{F}^+(U)$ one to one correspond to smooth function on $U$ that is $\mathcal{F}(U)$.

The question is ,consider the closed set $A$ ,we want to show that $$\{s:A\to \text{Et}(\mathcal{F})\mid p\circ s = \text{id}\}$$

One to one correspond to the set of function that defined on $A$ which has smooth extension to some neiborhood of $A$.

I can construct the desired function locally,which is simple since consider,the local section $s(x)$ for each $x$,there exist some smooth function $f\in \mathcal{F}(U)$ represent the $s(x) \in \mathcal{F}_x$,if $A$ open then it's just part of the proof of the natural isomorphism above.Using the fact that local section agree on a point ,will agree on a neiborhood,then invoke the sheaf condition can finish the proof,the question is there is no such neiborhood on the boundary

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Now that you have each function locally, you can glue them together using partitions of unity. Given a local section section $s: A \to \text{Et}(\mathcal{F})$, let $(f_x,U_x) = s(x) \in \mathcal{F}_x$. Then, consider the open neighborhood of $A$ given by
$$
U = \bigcup_{x \in A} U_x
$$
and consider a partition of unity $\{\rho_x\}_{x \in A}$ subordinated to the open covering $\{U_x\}_{x \in A}$. Then, we can define $f: U \to \mathbb{R}$ by
$$
f(y) = \sum_{x \in A} \rho_x (y) f_x (y)
$$
a smooth function in a neighborhood of $A$ by properties of the partition of unity.

Comment: thank you,will it be possible to construct such $f$ using sheaf condition?

Comment: I'm not sure... How did you prove that $\mathcal{F}^+(U)$ has a one-to-one correspondence with $\mathcal{F}(U)$? Because if you did it using the sheaf condition, I think the same argument is supposed to work.

Comment: You can see it from Raymond O. Wells, Jr Differential analysis on complex manifold page 58 theorem 2.2

Comment: Ok, I think I understand the problem. The construction I did works even if the section $s: A \to \text{Et}(\mathcal{F})$ is not continuous, and I wasn't thinking of continuity when I wrote, but if $s$ is continuous (as it should be, by the definition in Wells' book), I believe that defining $f: U \to \mathbb{R}$ given by
$$
f(y) = f_y(y)
$$
will work. You'll probably have to use continuity of $s$ to show the functions $f_x$ agree on intersections, then you can use the sheaf condition. I'm using the same notation here, $s(x) = (f_x, U_x)$ and $U = \bigcup_{x \in A} U_x$.

Comment: if we want to take the sheaf of holomorphic function for example,partition of unity does not work,since POU  provide "smooth" extension.

Comment: The extension needs not to be unique, but $f|_A$ is unique.